# phusion passenger vs raw process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm looking into tuning our [Phusion Passenger](https://phusionpassenger.com) with [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com) set up for deployment of Rails applications on AWS.  After going through all the documentation, I am leaning towards completely removing Passenger from the stack since I can spin up a bunch of little Docker instances pointing to Rails directly instead.

Am I missing something in the use of Passenger?

Since I have my applications behind an AWS load balancer, I'm not sure whether I need it or not.